# Aggregation within a index heirarchy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Currently, I have a dataframe with an index heirarchy for monthly cohorts. Here is how I grouped them.

```
grouped = dfsort.groupby(['Cohort','Lifetime_Revenue'])

cohorts = grouped.agg({'Customer_ID': pd.Series.nunique})
```

Which outputs:

```
Cohort  Lifetime_Revenue    Customer_ID
2014-01      149.9                1
2014-02      299.9                1
2014-03      269.91               1
             329.89               1
             899.88               1
2014-04      299.9                1
             674.91               2
2014-05      899.88               1
2014-06      824.89               1
```

And so on.

I was looking to get the total sum of the Lifetime revenue for each cohort as well as the total amount of users for a cohort.

Basically, I want to turn it into a regular database.

Anyone got any thoughts on this?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, lacking details. I would like to see how `grouped` is created. Preferably some of your input data as well.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it now. Let me grab the input data.

Comment: Are you looking for `dfsort.groupby('Cohort').agg({'Lifetime_revenue' : ['sum', 'count']})`?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)